# iterm2 colors not changing in when changing ANSI Colors

Tags: iterm2, color-profiles

When I change the ANSI colors in prefereces> profiles> colors >ANSI colors, the colors do not actually change in iterm. They change if I open tmux in iterm2 but not in the actually in iterm. Why is this and how do I fix it?